# fmt::format how to always print first n non-zero digits with leading zeroes

Tags: fmt

Given three floating point numbers

```
a = 1.0
b = 1.23456
c = 1.23456e-12
```

How can I always print the first `n` non-zero digits, with leading zeroes, if required. Desired output for `n=6`:

```
1.00000
1.23456
0.00000000000123456
```

I tried `fmt::format("{:.6f"}", number)` but this returns `0.00000` in the last case.

Comment: You cannot display `1.23456e-12` in 6 digits without exponent. And if you tell the fmt library to display 6 digits, it will display 6 digits and cut off anything that comes after.

Comment: @derpirscher I do not want to print it in 6 digits (see desired output). I want to print any zeroes + first `n` non-zero digits. I'll edit to make this clearer.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible with fmt. The `f` and `F` respectively uses a fixed point notation, that will cut off after `n` digits. And the `g` and `G` respectively may switch to an exponential display, depending on the magnitute of the value.

Comment: What you can do is, to check the magnitude of your value before formatting and then use the respective precision. Ie if you know, your number is `1.23456e-12` use `.18f` as precision for formatting ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way of doing this but you could do it in several steps:

1. Format using the exponent notation (`e`).
2. Extract the exponent.
3. Format using the fixed notation (`f`) adjusting the precision to account for the exponent.

For example:

```cpp
#include <fmt/core.h>

void print(double n) {
  auto s = fmt::format("{:e}", n);
  auto exp = atoi(s.substr(s.find('e') + 1).c_str());
  int precision = 6;
  if (exp < 0) precision -= exp;
  fmt::print("{:.{}f}\n", n, precision - 1);
}

int main() {
  print(1.0);
  print(1.23456);
  print(1.23456e-12);
}
```

This prints:

```
1.00000
1.23456
0.00000000000123456
```

https://godbolt.org/z/16n8s7TG3